# Headers are not getting extracted from PDF while extracting the table data from PDF using camelot

Tags: pdf-scraping, python-camelot

I am using camelot for table data extraction, however header are not getting extracted as part of the PDF.

Attaching the target 
PDF link below and target table are at page number 3 and 4, which need to extracted.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xniTIwpnNIdA_k4xvEARlVH97Lk-K2Yr/view?usp=sharing

One of the tables looks like below
[image]

I have seen the the camelot documentation and I think the problem is related to the **"Detect short lines"**

https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#detect-short-lines

However not able to resolve the problem by tweaking the **line_size_scaling** parameter.

Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I plotted the detected table boundary on page 3 using `$ camelot -p 3 lattice -plot contour 007.pdf`. Looks like Camelot isn't including the header row in the detected table boundary [bug 1] (see image below). Then I tried using the `table_areas` keyword argument with `flavor='lattice'` but then it didn't include the lines in the the specified table boundary [bug 2]. I've added these on the issue tracker as [#200](https://github.com/socialcopsdev/camelot/issues/200) and [#201](https://github.com/socialcopsdev/camelot/issues/201).

You can still use the `table_areas` keyword argument with `flavor='stream'` to get the table out.

Using CLI: `$ camelot -p 3 --output 007.csv --format csv stream -T 60,770,520,400 007.pdf`

Using API: `tables = camelot.read_pdf('007.pdf', pages='3', flavor='stream', table_areas=['60,770,520,400'])`

You can find the table boundary coordinates using the steps described here: https://camelot-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced.html#visual-debugging

Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vinayak, Thanks for the response. I have also plotted the the table boundaries and got the same result as header are not being part of the table.  Will track the bug number.

Comment: I am not able to create the tag  "python-camelot", as I don't have enough credits to do that,  will you please create  "python-camelot" tag. As I am using camelot So might have other question also.

Comment: I can see the tag. If you found this answer helpful, please accept it, thanks.